# Do all Tags need a #?

Tags: tags

Do all tags need # before them?   Am I correct in that tags are made up of keywords that must have # before them and a ; to separate them?

Also, is it true that Tags can be either public or private depending what I select and that a Note Board is always public?

Comment: what sharepoint version you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different kind of tags and the only place you need a hash `#` is in the Newsfeed. In the newsfeed you also need an at-sign `@` to mention a person in SharePoint.

In SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online the enterprise keywords can be added as a column in any list or library. You can allow for several tags in the column and they are indeed separated by a semicolon `;` but don't have the preceding hash.

In SharePoint 2010 you can add private tags on a document or an item and you can view them on your profile. Switching `refine by type` to private you will only see your private tags.

More to read:

1. [View my tags and notes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-my-tags-and-notes-7de3e885-747f-4f69-80b7-d9f601ff3cc2)
2. [Add an enterprise keywords column to a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-enterprise-keywords-column-to-a-list-or-library-314ce556-e4bf-4ef7-9939-6a1bedfc434a)

Comment: Thanks Benny. By the way, what is the difference between SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online? Should I make this a new separate question, or is it okay to ask you here? :) Thanks.